# Cs50 filter problem - reflect. Pixels dont change values, not sure why (C)

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to implement the reflect filter by saving the left pixel of a column and replacing it by its relative right pixel. Thing is I'm not getting the result I expected and the image stays the same. Maybe its not entering the while loop but logically it seems to me that it should.

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //int n = width;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n",width);
        int j = 0;
        int left = 0 + j;
        int right = width - 1 - j;
        while (j != width )
        {
            int pixRed = image[i][left].rgbtRed;
            int pixGreen = image[i][left].rgbtGreen;
            int pixBlue = image[i][left].rgbtBlue;

            image[i][left].rgbtRed = image[i][right].rgbtRed;
            image[i][left].rgbtGreen = image[i][right].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][left].rgbtBlue = image[i][right].rgbtBlue;

            image[i][right].rgbtRed = pixRed;
            image[i][right].rgbtGreen = pixGreen;
            image[i][right].rgbtBlue = pixBlue;
            j++;
            printf("%i\n",j);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: You should format your code properly to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have *unbalanced* braces in your posted code. But, I surmise your `return` is [would be] in the middle of the outer loop, so you'll only do one row.

You need to increment `left` and decrement `right`. As it is, you change `j` at the bottom of the inner loop, but don't adjust `left/right`

No need to use `.whatever`--we can just use whole `RGBTRIPLE`

Your indexing logic is a bit complex.

You're doing a lot of 2D indexing. Since the array has two dynamic dimensions, this means a *lot* of multiplying in the inner loop.

A separate pointer to the row can simplify the code and make it run a bit faster.

---

Here's the refactored version:

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void
reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // int n = width;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        RGBTRIPLE *row = &image[i][0];

        int left = 0;
        int right = width - 1;
        for (;  left < right;  ++left, --right) {
            RGBTRIPLE tmp = row[left];
            row[left] = row[right];
            row[right] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

---

We can also have `left` and `right` be pointers:

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void
reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // int n = width;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        RGBTRIPLE *left = &image[i][0];
        RGBTRIPLE *right = &left[width - 1];

        for (;  left < right;  ++left, --right) {
            RGBTRIPLE tmp = *left;
            *left = *right;
            *right = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I don't get what `RGBTRIPLE *right = &left[width - 1];` means. the expression in the squared brackets is assigned as an index to `&image`? how does it take one index if its had 2 dimensions? – yonatan goldin 8 hours ago

This is basic access of a 1D pointer within a 2D array. This is a *very* important concept to master.

Consider an array of WIDTH=8, HEIGHT=6. If we laid it out on paper, the cell indexing would look like:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 2D  | 0,0 | 0,1 | 0,2 | 0,3 | 0,4 | 0,5 | 0,6 | 0,7 |
| 1D  |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 2D  | 1,0 | 1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3 | 1,4 | 1,5 | 1,6 | 1,7 |
| 1D  |  8  |  9  | 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  | 14  | 15  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 2D  | 2,0 | 2,1 | 2,2 | 2,3 | 2,4 | 2,5 | 2,6 | 2,7 |
| 1D  | 16  | 17  | 18  | 19  | 20  | 21  | 22  | 23  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 2D  | 3,0 | 3,1 | 3,2 | 3,3 | 3,4 | 3,5 | 3,6 | 3,7 |
| 1D  | 24  | 25  | 26  | 27  | 28  | 29  | 30  | 31  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 2D  | 4,0 | 4,1 | 4,2 | 4,3 | 4,4 | 4,5 | 4,6 | 4,7 |
| 1D  | 32  | 33  | 34  | 35  | 36  | 37  | 38  | 39  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 2D  | 5,0 | 5,1 | 5,2 | 5,3 | 5,4 | 5,5 | 5,6 | 5,7 |
| 1D  | 40  | 41  | 42  | 43  | 44  | 45  | 46  | 47  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Some definitions/code:

```
#define WIDTH   8
#define HEIGHT  6

// 2D array:
RGBTRIPLE d2[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

// pointer to access d2 as 1D array/vector:
RGBTRIPLE *d1 = &d2[0][0];

// pointer to cell from "2D" array:
RGBTRIPLE *p2;

// pointer to cell from "1D" array:
RGBTRIPLE *p1;
```

Sometimes, rather than referring to `row` and `column` numbers/indexes, it can be easier to talk about `y` and `x` coordinates/indexes respectively.

To get the address of a cell from the 2D array, for a given x,y point, we want:

```
p2 = &d2[y][x];
```

To get the *same* address using the 1D pointer, we want:

```
p1 = &d1[(y * WIDTH) + x];
```

At this point, `p2` and `p1` will have the *same* address.

Note that while computer languages (like C) know about [and support] 2D arrays, [most] computer architectures do *not*. So, the compiler must take a statement like the one above for `p2`, convert it [internally] into something like the one for `p1` and generate the code from that.

For a point `[1][0]`, the linear index to use is: `(1 * WIDTH) + 0`, which is: `(1 * 8) + 0` or `8`.

For a point `[1][WIDTH - 1]`, the linear index to use is: `(1 * WIDTH) + (WIDTH - 1)`, which is `(1 * 8) + (8 - 1)` or `15`.

So, if we had:

```
left = &d2[1][0];
right = &d2[1][WIDTH - 1];
```

Then, we would also have:

```
left = &d1[8];
right = &d1[15];
```

But, this is also true:

```
right = &left[15 - 8];
right = &left[7];
```

Here, `7` is also `WIDTH - 1`.

If you look at the above table, for every 2D coordinate, we have a 1D offset. Again, for `[3][5]`, the offset is: `29`

This is also: `(3 * 8) + 5`

I'd print out the above table on *paper* and use a pencil to do some calculations by hand until you understand how to traverse an array using 2D and 1D.

For example, in the following code, *all* the `for` loops do exactly the *same* thing to the `d2` array and access each individual cell in the *same* order:

```
for (int y = 0;  y < HEIGHT;  ++y) {
    for (int x = 0;  x < WIDTH;  ++x)
        d2[y][x] += 23;
}

int end = HEIGHT * WIDTH;
for (int off = 0;  off < end;  ++off)
    d1[off] += 23;

RGBTRIPLE *p1 = &d2[0][0];

// NOTE: e1 and e2 are the same
RGBTRIPLE *e2 = &d2[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
RGBTRIPLE *e1 = &p1[HEIGHT * WIDTH];

for (;  p1 < e1;  ++p1)
    *p1 += 23;
```

Comment: I don't get what ` RGBTRIPLE *right = &left[width - 1]; ` means. the expression in the squared brackets is assigned as an index to ` &image `? how does it take one index if its had 2 dimensions?